# How to show properties of a list in a list in a listview?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I am implementing an application in wpf , MVVM pattern.
I want to implement a listview with objects. These objects contains a list. On default this list contains only 1 object. But in the listview, I want to show that certain object. So the properties of the object in the list. This is my first problem.
But I also have to be able to have more objects in this list. My second problem is that i don't really know how to realise this? And i also have to show the properties of these objects in the listview. 
Maybe a treeview? but i don't get how that i got to begin on this..

Someone with some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arbitrarily nest DataTemplates, e.g.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <!-- Internal Manchines list gets its own ListView -->
            <GridViewColumn Header="Machines">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Machines}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Manufacturer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Manufacturer}"/>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Occupation"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Occupation}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Status"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This can be improved in terms of alignment, e.g. you could set up a Grid in the DataTemplate with a shared size column to make all lists the same width (making the internal columns align might be a bit hard though)

Further you could define a style to collapse empty lists (which otherwise would show the header without items).